# Is there a way to find an element in a list and delete items after it that are of a specific type without using indicies?

Tags: list, kotlin, boolean

I have a project that needs me to remove items if one of the properties of the item I'm trying to find within the list is true. Just so it's easier understand the project I am pasting all code needed to understand it below.

```
fun main() {
    val acct1 = AccountId(72)

    val calendars = mutableListOf<CalendarDrawerCalendarItem>()
    val calendars2 = mutableListOf<CalendarDrawerCalendarItem>()

    calendars.add(CalendarDrawerCalendarItem(CalendarDescriptor(acct1, CalendarId(acct1, 3),"toast", true)))
    calendars.add(CalendarDrawerCalendarItem(CalendarDescriptor(acct1, CalendarId(acct1, 4), "chicken", false)))
    calendars.add(CalendarDrawerCalendarItem(CalendarDescriptor(acct1, CalendarId(acct1, 5), "pizza", true)))
    calendars2.add(CalendarDrawerCalendarItem(CalendarDescriptor(acct1, CalendarId(acct1, 1), "bagel", true)))

// These are example calls to collapse

    collapse(calendars, CalendarDrawerGroupItem(true, CalendarGroupDescriptor( acct1, "My Calendars")))
    collapse(calendars2, CalendarDrawerGroupItem(false, CalendarGroupDescriptor(acct1, "Group Calendars")))
}

fun collapse(calendars: List<CalendarDrawerListItem>, group: CalendarDrawerGroupItem): List<CalendarDrawerListItem> {

    val collapsedResults = mutableListOf<CalendarDrawerListItem>()
    val findGroupGiven = group

    collapsedResults.addAll(calendars)
    
    if (collapsedResults.contains(findGroupGiven)) {
        group.collapsed = true
        // logic for deleting items here

    }

    return collapsedResults
}
```

I'll also put the classes so you can see how they're defined

```
data class AccountId(
    val accountId: Int
)

data class CalendarId(
    val accountId: AccountId,
    val calendarId: Int)

data class CalendarDescriptor(
    val accountId: AccountId,
    val calendarId: CalendarId,
    val name: String,
    val isGroupCalendar: Boolean
)

data class CalendarGroupDescriptor(
    val accountId: AccountId,
    val name: String,
)


sealed class CalendarDrawerListItem

data class CalendarDrawerGroupItem(var collapsed: Boolean, val groupDescriptor: CalendarGroupDescriptor) : CalendarDrawerListItem()

data class CalendarDrawerCalendarItem(val calendarDescriptor: CalendarDescriptor) : CalendarDrawerListItem()
```

The first step I have done is I must find the given group from the group variable, within calendars. (I did this with the contains() method). Next when I find the group I have to set its collapsed variable to true and any CalendarDrawerCalendarItems after it have to be deleted.

The input will look something like (the exact numbers and values are not the important part):

```
Input: 
calendars:
CDGroupItem(collapsed = false, groupDescriptor = GroupDescriptor(accountId = 1, name = "My calendars"))
CDCalendarItem(calendarDescriptor = CalendarDescriptor(accountId = 1, calendarId = 1, isGroup = false))
CDCalendarItem(calendarDescriptor = CalendarDescriptor(accountId = 1, calendarId = 2, isGroup = false))
CDCalendarItem(calendarDescriptor = CalendarDescriptor(accountId = 1, calendarId = 3, isGroup = false))
CDGroupItem(collapsed = false, groupDescriptor = GroupDescriptor(accountId = 1, name = "Group calendars"))
CDCalendarItem(calendarDescriptor = CalendarDescriptor(accountId = 1, calendarId = 4, isGroup = true))
CDCalendarItem(calendarDescriptor = CalendarDescriptor(accountId = 1, calendarId = 5, isGroup = true))



group: CDGroupItem(collapsed = false, groupDescriptor = GroupDescriptor(accountId = 1, name = "My calendars"))
```

The output should look something like this:

```
Output:
CDGroupItem(collapsed = true, groupDescriptor = GroupDescriptor(accountId = 1, name = "My calendars"))
CDGroupItem(collapsed = false, groupDescriptor = GroupDescriptor(accountId = 1, name = "Group calendars"))
CDCalendarItem(calendarDescriptor = CalendarDescriptor(accountId = 1, calendarId = 4, isGroup = true))
CDCalendarItem(calendarDescriptor = CalendarDescriptor(accountId = 1, calendarId = 5, isGroup = true))
```

Any group item that has its collapsed boolean set to true should have all calendar items deleted after it since its collapsed is set to true. Again the names and numbers are not super important. The collapsed bool is. How can I do this without hardcoding or using indicies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code doesn't use that input and output as-is so I can only give you a general example, but you could use a *fold*:

```
val result = calendars.fold(mutableListOf<CalendarDrawerListItem>()) { items, current ->
    // basically 'is there a last item stored, and is it a group item, and is it collapsed'
    val lastStoredIsCollapsed =
        (items.lastOrNull() as? CalendarDrawerGroupItem)?.collapsed == true
    if (current is CalendarDrawerCalendarItem && lastStoredIsCollapsed) items
    else items.apply { add(current) }
}
```

It basically pipes out each item into a list, but if the last one it stored is a `CalendarDrawerGroupItem` with `collapsed` set to *true*, it drops drawer items. If the last one is a non-collapsed group item, it can store a drawer item, and that means the next drawer item will be stored (since the last item isn't a collapsed group)

---

**edit**: here's the `for` loop equivalent if it helps, with the full logic for when a calendar is *not* dropped (the logic in my other example is for whether it *should* be dropped, which can be condensed a bit):

```
// assuming 'calendars' is your list of items with 'collapsed' set appropriately
val result = mutableListOf<CalendarDrawerListItem)
for (calendar in calendars) {
    val lastStored = result.lastOrNull()
    when {
        lastStored == null ->
            result.add(calendar)
        lastStored is CalendarDrawerGroupItem && !lastStored.collapsed ->
            result.add(calendar)
        lastStored is CalendarDrawerCalendarItem ->
            result.add(calendar)
    }
}
return result
```

---

If you're asking how to actually mutate your list so a `collapsed` property is set to *true*, that would be easy if the property was a `var` in your data class. Since it's a `val` you'll have to do something like this:

```
val calendarInputWithCollapsedSet = calendars.map { calendar ->
    if ((calendar as? CalendarDrawerGroupItem)?.groupDescriptor == group.groupDescriptor)
        calendar.copy(collapsed = true) else calendar
}
```

So if you find a matching group (you'll have to work out how to match them, I'm guessing) you transform it into a copy with its `collapsed` property set

And then you can run the `fold` or whatever on that new list.

Comment: Where would this go in context of my code? Am I replacing collapsedResults with this? Do I still need the if statement I have inside of collapse?

Comment: I've never seen or used fold() before so I have no idea where this fits in basically.

Comment: @corteg2501 you run it on your list of calendar items like in your input. It's basically like a `for` loop where you create an empty list and add items to it as you iterate over the collection. It just drops any `CalendarDrawerCalendarItem`s that follow a `CalendarDrawerGroupItem` with its `collapsed` property set to *true* - so it'll collapse *all* the groups with `collapse = true`

Comment: @corteg2501 I've added a for-loop version in case it makes things clearer (and reversed the logic so it's checking for the cases where it would *add* to the list, instead of checking for the cases where it would *drop* an item

Comment: @corteg2501 And yeah, this is just creating `collapsedResults` - you can look at my test code here: https://pl.kotl.in/SHlo2flq1 I had to add the groups to the input list myself, and change the `collapsed` value to *true* to check it worked. If you're asking how to actually set the `collapsed` value in your list as well, I'll add that to my answer

Comment: This is amazing to me. Are there any resources you used to get better with kotlin?

Comment: @corteg2501 honestly just solving problems helps, so answering stuff on here and seeing how other people did things is a great way to learn! Especially getting familiar with all the stuff in `kotlin.collections` and how it works. But for this approach, I think it's from learning a bit of functional programming (I did *F#*) where this kind of transforming pipeline approach is common. Do you get how it works though? The idea is kinda simple (basically how you'd do it by hand) even if the implementation isn't as obvious. And ain't nothing wrong with a `for` loop!